# WebResource.axd 404 error - windows server 2008 64bit

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

We Installed new application in our dedicated server. I struggle with an issue for the last few days. I get 404 no found in all WebResource.axd requests.

I have uninstall and install .net 2.0 - I have .net 3.5 installed as well.
using webresource decrypter I found that many JS files, such as WebForms.js generate the erorr.

I check the iis handlers mapping for .axd

I disable http comp.

What else could be?

Answer (score 0):

Switch IIS7 to run in Classic mode.